# How to get the deepest route in taxonomy breadcrumb

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm using Hierarchical select to save my nodes in a term and that term's ancestors.And I'm using taxonomy breadcrumb to display my node's breadcrumb.however I would like to display the deepest Breadcrumb for the node but it only displays the root term.e.g:
I have the following vocabulary structure:

parent1
--term1
--term2

and I have a node called node1 with term1 reference field.and hierarchical select also adds it to parent1.

Currently in the breadcrumbs what i get is : parent1 >> node1
what I want to get is : parent1 >> term1 >> node1

Comment: Not sure, but I think [Crumbs](https://drupal.org/project/crumbs) taxonomy plugin chooses the deepest taxonomy trail.

Comment: Otherwise you should file an issue in the [taxonomy breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_breadcrumb) issue queue. But it seems this module is "Unsupported".